# Pandas automatically converts string to date

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need to work with a csv file in which one column contains values like these: 1/2, 2/1, 3/1, etc.

When I load the csv into a pandas data frame object, automatically the values look like:01-Feb,02-Jan,03-Jan, etc.

How can I load this csv into a dataframe object in which the values of this columns are converted as strings?

I have tried this

```
df = pd.read_csv("/Users/Name/Desktop/QM/data.csv", encoding='latin-1',dtype=str)
```

But the dates remains

Comment: Are you sure it is `read_csv` and not `read_excel` ?

Comment: Yeap. My company gave me an .excel and I converted into .csv because the file was full colors, filters and stuff.

Comment: hmmm, so problem is converting excel to csv. Pandas working correct.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like there is format for that column some way...

anyway, you can just convert back to string following this [Pandas Series.dt.strftime](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-dt-strftime/#:%7E:text=Pandas%20Series.dt.strftime%20%28%29%20function%20is%20used%20to%20convert,the%20python%20standard%20library.%20Syntax%3A%20Series.dt.strftime%20%28%2Aargs%2C%20%2A%2Akwargs%29)